# There is no extension able to load the configuration for "web_profiler"

Tags: symfony

I'm quite new so Symfony2 and want to create a new environment called "dp". But for some reason I keep getting errors.

```
FileLoaderLoadException: Cannot import resource "/a/b/c/d/e/app/config/config_dev.yml" from "/a/b/c/d/e/app/config/config_dp.yml".
InvalidArgumentException: There is no extension able to load the configuration for "web_profiler" (in /a/b/c/d/e/app/config/config_dev.yml). Looked for namespace "web_profiler", found "framework", "security", "twig", "monolog", "swiftmailer", "doctrine", "assetic", "sensio_framework_extra", "jms_security_extra", "smarty", "bela_meter", "bela_invoice", "bela_util"
```

I followed the Symfony2 [documentation steps](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/environments.html) 
The contents of app/config/config_dp.yml is

```
imports:
- { resource: config_dev.yml }
```

And web/app_dp.php contains:

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('dp', true);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
$kernel->handle(Request::createFromGlobals())->send();
```

How can I fix this? config_dev.yml environment works flawless.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

By default, `WebProfilerBundle` is loaded in `dev` and `test` environments only. Find this code snippet in your `AppKernel` class:

```php
if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
    $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
    // ...
}
```

and append your new environment name to the array:

```php
array('dev', 'test', 'dp')
```

Comment: Great, also works this way with Symfony 3 (3.1.4). Just had to further add a `router_ENV.php` to the FrameworkBundle, more specifically: under `vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/`, else it would throw an error. Maybe this is new in Symfony 3?  Anyways, I'm wondering why this info isn't in the official Symfony documentation? O.o

Answer (score 2):

Very simple in Symfony 4. Just add your new environment to the bundles file.

Open config/bundles.php

```
Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle::class => ['dev' => true, 'test' => true]
```

becomes

```
Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle::class => ['dev' => true, 'test' => true, 'YOUR_NEW_ENV' => true]
```

Answer (score -1):

I have been using this format below, first I enable the web profiler to all the environments, and then only disable it for Prod.
In my case, I have at least 8 different environments before Production and it's important to me to have the web profiler working in all these environments, so instead of enabling one by one, makes more sense to just enable it for all and disable for Prod.

```php
Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle::class => ['all' => true, 'prod' => false]
```

Comment: Please explain if it's specific to some versions of Symfony and why it's necessary.